# Android приложение для Web-сайта

Tags: android, веб-программирование, парсер, мобильные-приложения

Как парсить изображения через Jsoup? Хочу сделать приложение Андроид для сайта. API отсутствует. Картинки думаю вставлять через ListView.

Comment: Что означает "парсить изображёния"?

Comment: Выбираем элемент, описывающий изображение, достаём из него ссылку, загружаем по ней картинку.

Comment: используйте Glide или Picasso